# Kernel Error in Jupyter Notebook, don't know what to do, am new to this

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Kath.000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1699, in _execute

```
result = await result
```

File "C:\Users\Kath.000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run

```
yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
```

File "C:\Users\Kath.000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 72, in post

```
type=mtype))
```

File "C:\Users\Kath.000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run

```
value = future.result()
```

File "C:\Users\Kath.000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run

```
yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
```

File "C:\Users\Kath.000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session

```
kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
```

File "C:\Users\Kath.000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run

```
value = future.result()
```

File "C:\Users\Kath.000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run

```
yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
```

File "C:\Users\Kath.000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 101, in start_kernel_for_session

```
self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
```

File "C:\Users\Kath.000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run

```
value = future.result()
```

File "C:\Users\Kath.000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 209, in wrapper

```
yielded = next(result)
```

File "C:\Users\Kath.000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 168, in start_kernel

```
super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
```

File "C:\Users\Kath.000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel

```
km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
```

File "C:\Users\Kath.000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 240, in start_kernel

```
self.write_connection_file()
```

File "C:\Users\Kath.000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 547, in write_connection_file

```
kernel_name=self.kernel_name
```

File "C:\Users\Kath.000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 212, in write_connection_file

```
with secure_write(fname) as f:
```

File "C:\Users\Kath.000\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in **enter**

```
return next(self.gen)
```

File "C:\Users\Kath.000\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 102, in secure_write

```
with os.fdopen(os.open(fname, open_flag, 0o600), mode) as f:
```

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\Kath.000\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-451bd345-5996-4658-8c31-dbdb280931d9.json'

Answer (score 1):

I guess from your log that you also installed Anaconda3. I installed Anaconda 2019.10 for Windows yesterday and I'm having the same error.

### Simple answer

Downgrading anaconda to 2019.07 which is the previous version.

[How to downgrade anacondafrom Anaconda Emvironments GUI.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaEwj.png)

1. Open Anaconda Navigator.
2. Change to Environments tab.
3. Right click 'anaconda' in list.
4. Slide mouse cursor to 'Mark for specific version installation'.
5. Select '2019.07'.
6. Apply the downgrade.

> 2019-10-25 Add: After I tried upgrading anaconda to '2019.10' once again. jupyter_client became ver.5.3.4, not ver.5.3.3.This change solved the problem on my environment.
>
> 2019-11-12 Add: The same issue occurred on another PC. I noticed that "Mark specific version installation" is grayed out after a new installation. "Mark specific version installation" is enabled after running "Update Index ...". Although I downgraded anaconda using the same procedure as the last time, you may be able to solve this issue simply by upgrading anaconda.

[jupyter_client became ver.5.3.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rAVA.png)

### Long answer

From here, 
[Kernel error in jupyter notebook #4909](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4937)
. The following components seem to be the cause.

- jupyter_client 5.3.3
- pywin32 223

The solution is mentioned as below.

- Downgrading jupyter_client to version 5.3.1.

  - conda install jupyter_client=5.3.1
- Or upgrading pywin32 to version 224.

  - conda install pywin32=224

I operated them from the GUI of Anaconda Navigator. However both of them are not worked on my anaconda environment. I tried 'conda install pywin32=224' from Terminal but it stopped in the middle of processing. Probably dependencies between packages prevent these operations. I didn't want to spend time to installing software, so I choose to downgrade anaconda to the previous version.

### Consideration in taking this solution.

This solution prevents you from installing other latest packages. For example, numpy=1.16.4, scikit-learn=0.21.2 scipy=1.2.1 become unavailable.

I hope that this information is helpful to you.